# Instead of alert to do a notification with css

Tags: jquery, css

How can i do to this process instead of alert to show a notification with jquery css? I have this:

```
var count_cases = -1;
setInterval(function(){    
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "file.php",
        success : function(response){
            if (count_cases != -1 && count_cases != response) alert('new record on i_case');
            count_cases = response;
        }
    });
},1000);
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you mean by "notification"?

Comment: You're probably looking for a javascript plugin for notifications like [Toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/)

Comment: Yes. take a look here, it will show-up in the corner: http://ned.im/noty/#/about

Comment: or: http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

Comment: You can start with [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kzan7wc4/). It shows you how to control the notification via Javascript and how to style it via CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create
`<div class="anything"></div>` in HTML

Than in JQuery

```
var count_cases = -1;
setInterval(function(){    
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "file.php",
    success : function(response){
        if (count_cases != -1 && count_cases != response){
            $(".anything").text(response);
        }
        count_cases = response;
    }
});
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, here **selector** is a notification tag like `<span>`,`<div>` in your page, change selector as per your requirements

```
var count_cases = -1;
setInterval(function(){    
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "file.php",
    success : function(response){
        if (count_cases != -1 && count_cases != response)         $("selector").text("new record on i_case");$("selector").css("background-color","red");
        count_cases = response;
    }
});
```

},1000);

Comment: OK good, and if i want to show a username instead of i_case? how can i do that?

Comment: if solve your problem, accept the answer because its useful to others also

Comment: are you getting customer name from db? if yes means need file.php code content to decide

Comment: yes i'm getting the name..

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you're wanting to accomplish there's a great "notification/status" popup jquery extension called
[Toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/)

Comment: Yes, but with the toastr i don't know to integrate the php file , a little help ?

Comment: it's just a matter of outputting the appropriate html & javascript. `echo '<link href="toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>';`  `echo '<script src="toastr.js"></script>';`  (the first two should probably be part of your general template)  `echo '<script>toastr.info("Hey there!");</script>';`

Comment: Thanks Brad! U're a nice man!